# show no of occurences of two strings in same line on access logs

Tags: awk, grep

Say we have multiple access logs, in the format of the bellow access log line sample:

```
66.249.72.214 - - [05/Nov/2011:12:47:37 +0200] "GET /produktas/565638 HTTP/1.1" 200 4699 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

I am trying to grep for the cases where two strings are both on the same line doing:

```
grep "/produktas" accesslog* | grep -c "200"
```

and that works, but it only prints the number of occurences of these two strings in all the accesslog files, i.e. for a total of 40 occurences in all the log files combined, that would simply output "40".

What I would like to do is search each line for having word1 and word2, print the number of occurences in each file with its corresponding filename and a total count of them, as in the example below:

```
accesslog_01052019:23    
accesslog_02052019:17    
40
```

Is that possible? Please note that my grep command has no "-o" option.

Comment: there are many flows with your design. First of all, you are [piping](https://www.guru99.com/linux-pipe-grep.html) your commands, so any line containing "word1" will be used as start point to look for "word2". Second, you ask `grep -c "word2"`, meaning you'll only count lines with both "word1" and "word2", in your example, 40 lines. Please provide a valid example of the accesslog files on which we can test scripts.

Comment: I use pipping because *I want* the first word to be used as a starting point to look for the second. I have provided a sample access log line.

Comment: [edit] your question to contain concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: You mention that `-o` is not provided. Is this a constraint?

Comment: no, on the man page the -o and when trying to use either -o or -E i get an illegal argument error, running an old sunOS version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT1:*** After chatting with OP came to know that OP needs to print total matching count number too, if that is the case then following may help.

```
nawk '
FNR==1{
  if(count){
     close(file)
     print file":"count
  }
  file=FILENAME
  count=""
}
/word1/ && /word2/{
  count++
  total++
}
END{
  if(count){
     print file":"count
  }
  print "Total count is:" total
}'  access_log*
```

---

---

Could you please try following. I haven't tested it since no samples are given. After chatting with OP got to know OP's O.S is Sun O.S so please change `awk` to `nawk` for following code for Sun O.S

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  if(count){
     close(file)
     print file":"count
  }
  file=FILENAME
  count=""
}
/word1/ && /word2/{
  count++
}
END{
  if(count){
     print file":"count
  }
}' accesslog*
```

---

---

Let's say following and Input_files.

```
cat accesslog_01052019
word1 word2
word1 test test test1223224 word2
word1
wrjnjrnbjrnjn
cat accesslog_02052019
word1 word2
word1 test test test1223224 word2
word1
wrjnjrnbjrnjn
```

Now when I run above code it gives me right results as follows.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  if(count){
     close(file)
     print file":"count
  }
  file=FILENAME
  count=""
}
/word1/ && /word2/{
  count++
}
END{
  if(count){
     print file":"count
  }
}' accesslog*
accesslog_01052019:2
accesslog_02052019:2
```